# Avoid duplicated UDP multicast on bonding NICs

Tags: udp, multicast

I have two NICs , eth0 and eth1.They are bonding to bond0 and IP address of bond0 is 10.2.1.101 . When I try to send an UDP multicast to 10.2.1.101 , both eth0 and eth1 receive the packet , that is , bond0 receives two packets . 
Is it correct or what I should do two aviod this ? 
I can't receive duplicated packets on bond0 .

Could anybody suggest me how to do about this ?

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends entirely on how the bond is implemented, and SO probably isn't the right place - maybe SuperUser or if there's a Networking SE.

Comment: Hi Nick, The bonding options is IEEE 802.3ad Link Bundling and must be this. Can you do me a favor about this ?

Comment: has this been answered some other way? would be good to know the answer, even if it's a link to something else...